# Has an airplane ever been launched from a train?

Tags: aviation-history, takeoff

Presumably helicopters have landed and lifted off railroad flat cars.

***Has an airplane ever been launched from a train?***

[image]

(my artwork)

[image]

[F-84 during project ZELL testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-length_launch) (info provided by jwenting)

Comment: That looks too steep, you’ll launch into a stall. Pretty much you want it flat and pointed in the direction the train is traveling. And a heckuva lot of chains to hold it down before takeoff.

Comment: Has a kid ever releasesd a balloon from a train? I would believe someone once did.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "train" and "airplane": [NASA Considering Rail Gun Launch System to the Stars](https://www.universetoday.com/73536/nasa-considering-rail-gun-launch-system-to-the-stars/)

Comment: I don't really see an operational need for such a system, now or in the past. A catapult launch from a train like that should be no harder to accomplish than from a rolling, pitching, cruiser in the north Atlantic, which was done regularly during WW2, except that there's far less room to work on the aircraft as trains tend to be rather narrow, more so than a seaplane hangar on those ships was.

Comment: @jwenting There are two important differences: 1) trains are usually segmented to get round bends, so the limit on runway length is harsher than on a carrier; 2) a train can't turn into wind. I agree about it being a bit pointless.

Comment: @DanHulme I'm not talking about carriers, I'm talking about catapult rails installed on transport ships, cruisers, and battleships to launch floatplanes. A system similar to those could be installed on a train and needs no straight track. They usually didn't bother steering into the wind either, but shot the plane over the side with a prayer to the gods of war that it would fly.

Comment: Where would it land?

Comment: The first photo clearly is a fake. The carriage is from a railroad gun and the airplane photo has been pasted in.

Comment: I can't find any evidence of train launch, but recall that in Douglas Baders autobiography he flew a Tiger Moth alongside of a train, remaining stationery relative to the train as the stall speed (flying into a strong headwind) was slower than the train. Given a TGV or similar trains can exceed 250kmh, world theoretical be possible for a light aircraft to take off without a catapult. @Michael Hall, not trying to answer a question raised in a comment, but the fighter aircraft ditched at sea. CAM ships also steered into the wind when launching fighters https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAM_ship

Comment: @MichaelHall in the case of ship launched aircraft, they'd typically land in the water close to the ship to be hauled back aboard by a crane (or to sink, with the pilot being recovered by one of the ship's boats). In case of project ZEL and similar systems, anything flat and long enough, or the pilot'd eject close to friendly forces.

Comment: @jwenting - Absolutely true about ships recovering aircraft from the water. As an interesting side note some Japanese subs carried recon aircraft that had no gear or pontoons so the pilot had to 'crash' next to the sub to be recovered (it was strictly a one way trip). Americans and Germans also had sub aircraft but I think they were all recoverable . Anyway, CRASHING apparently is an acceptable military option!

Comment: @jwzumwalt British launched Hurricane and Spitfire fighters from freighters using catapults before there were escort carriers for Atlantic convoys. They too had to crashland next to the ship and the pilot was fished out of the ocean, if he lived long enough.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a train, but Brendan O'Brien (with the O'Brien Flying Circus) has an act where he lands a Piper Cub on a moving trailer, towed by a car. There are some [YouTube-clips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW3qNmXN5kQ) showing this, including a take-off (around 1:50). Regarding your earlier comment on 'as close at it gets': I think this is it.

Comment: landing in this context is a lot easier than taking off, if you have an aircraft like a Cub that's capable of extremely short landing distances.

Comment: As noted in my answer, O'Brien also performs a take-off, at around 1:50 in the video. Of course, doing this with a Cub is something entirely different than with a larger/heavier craft. The question, however, was asking about 'an[y] airplane'.

Answer (score 4):

Not a train, but project ZEL comes closest to what you're looking at.

[image]

During the 1950s the USAF had the idea to launch combat loaded jet fighters from inside nuclear hardened buildings and caves using a short launch rail to guide the aircraft and large rocket bottles strapped to it.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-length_launch)

The idea was to have a fighter capability after an initial nuclear attack. I had an old VHS tape about the project, it was impressive and scary what they did.

For the initial testing a launch system was built onto a heavy truck, an F-100 mounted on it using a crane, and the pilot would get in and be shot into the air by remote control.

Later the ramp was built into a modified Matador or Mace cruise missile launch bunker, the tail clearing the roof by just inches as the F-100 was launched in a massive cloud of black smoke.

The program was eventually abandoned, but no doubt provided a lot of information about structural integrity and forces inside rocket silos.

Answer (score 1):

While it’s not specifically a train, [this tweet](https://twitter.com/GuillermoBGR/status/1286095436546281477) shows a float plane launched from the back of a trailer. The principle of launching from an unpowered, towed platform is similar to the scenario in your question.

Comment: As much as part of me wants to say, not a direct answer - delete, I have to admit that this is actually one of the most interesting videos I've seen lately. Nice find!

Comment: I was in doubt myself, but per jwzumwalt's [comment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53125/has-an-airplane-ever-been-launched-from-a-train/54625#comment140118_53444) indicating openness to "as close as it gets", an answer seemed more appropriate.

Comment: This type of Cessna stalls at ~60mph (less if it is light or in ground effect), so pulling the plane above 60mph is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind ZELL was to be able to disperse aircraft away from airfields, reducing the risk that the aircraft will be damaged in an attack on the airfield. Using rails misses the point of dispersal: you swap one easily identifiable, stationary target (airfield) for an easily identifiable, limited-movement target (train on rails).

You also have the problem that the size of rail cargo is severely limited by the loading gauge (i.e. the largest height and width of a rail vehicle). All obstacles around the track (overhead catenaries, signalling, tunnels, platforms) are designed to fit around this loading gauge. This means you have to remove the wings and tailplanes from your aircraft when you move the train, increasing reaction time.

It's much easier (and you get a much larger selection of hiding places) to hide a lorry with an assembled aircraft on top than to hide a train with same. 
You also get a much larger selection of suitable roads to travel on.

Answer (score -3):

After many Google searches and investigating on this topic, I find no evidence that an airplane has ever been launched from a train.

First of all, it would be unlikely for a person to risk an entire airplane along with themselves doing something so dangerous. By considering this fact, I doubt that an airplane has ever been launched from a train.

Second of all, by attempting such a thing would risk a catastrophe. This would probably cause an explosion that would no be so pretty.

So I have come to the conclusion that an airplane has never been launched from a train.

Comment: Seeing as people have launched fully combat loaded fighter aircraft from inside buildings (see project ZEL) you should reevaluate your "unlikely for a person to risk an entire airplane along with themselves" :)

Comment: @ jwenting - If you provide this as an answer that is not a train, but as close as it gets, I will mark it as the best plausible answer.